# What function should I replace onchange with for it to work without tampering with the slider first

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

On my site: alainbruno.nl/form.html, you'll see the form "Race" and the slider "Age". With the function i have the min and max of the slider age will only correctly change when you first use the slider before selecting a different race. What to do?

Excuse me if the code isnt displayed as code, i'm writing this from my phone and it doesnt give any additional instructions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>Character Creation</title>
</head>
<script                   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
         $(function(){
             //Range
            var slider = $("#slider"), val =         slider.val(), output = $("#output");
             output.html(val);
            slider.on("change", function(){
                output.html($(this).val());

            $('#Race').change(function ()                  {
  if (this.value == "faela") {
      $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 8,
         'max': 52
      });
    }
if (this.value == "human") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 14,
        'max': 76
      });
  }
if (this.value == "domovoi") {
     $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 26,
        'max': 254
       });
   }
if (this.value == "arcon") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 11,
        'max': 91
     });
  }
if (this.value == "tsaaran") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 2,
         'max': 28
      });
    }
   $('#slider').val('max' / 2);
   output.html('Slide');
 });
            });
        });
     </script>
 <body>
 <h1>Form</h1>
 <form>
  <fieldset>
 <legend>Appearance</legend>
 <p>
 <label>
 Select Race:
 </label>
  <select id="Race">
 <option value="human">Human</option>
 <option value="faela">Faela</option>
 <option value="domovoi">Domovoi</option>
 <option value="arcon">Arcon</option>
 <option value="tsaaran">Tsaaran</option>
 </select>

  <label for="range">Select Age:</label> <input         type="range" min="14" max="76" id="slider" value="10" name="range"><span id="output">.    </span>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the jquery-ui to the page. No slider, there is.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you here, I just started javascript. jquery-ui would be a library? Could you (or anyone else) link me to something that explains the basic of JQuery(ui)

Comment: God this mobile phone is killing me, I made a html5 range slider.. But it dissapeared haha

Comment: +1 because you write code on mobile device ... lol

Comment: I've updated my answer with some info about jQuery-ui and the `input` field you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap this in the dom ready function.
And I guess it should work.

```
    //Range
    var slider = $("#slider"), val = slider.val(), output = $("#output");
    output.html(val);

    slider.on('change', function(){
        output.html($(this).val());
    });

    $('#Race').on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value == "faela") {
            $('#slider').prop({
                'min': 8,
                'max': 52
            });
        }
        else if (value == "human") {
            $('#slider').prop({
                'min': 14,
                'max': 76
              });
        }
        else if (value == "domovoi") {
            $('#slider').prop({
                'min': 26,
                'max': 254
            });
        }
        else if (value == "arcon") {
            $('#slider').prop({
                'min': 11,
                'max': 91
            });
        }
        else if (value == "tsaaran") {
            $('#slider').prop({
                'min': 2,
                'max': 28
            });
        }
        $('#slider').val('max' / 2);
        output.html('Slide');
    });
```

FYI: The `input` with `type="range"` is very [new in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.range.html) and is not supported in Internet explorer and Firefox.

If you use the [jQuery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/), you can use the [jQuery-ui slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) which will work on most modern browsers and most devices.

EDIT: I tried the page in chrome and the slider does work, even after a race was selected. It does not keep it's value because you reset the min and max properties.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks, did not know about DOM wrapping, looked it up and it makes alot of sense now! jQuery looks sweet too, thanks again buddy

Answer (score 0):

refer [this URL](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) for JQUERY UI for sliders
html 5 sliders  is NOT supported by many browsers. (incliding Firefox)

If you want to do with html5 slider, create a function , say set_min_max, that changes the slider value. call that function on document.ready as well as on change.

```
    function set_min_max(select){
         if (select.val() == "faela") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 8,
        'max': 52
    });
}
if (select.val() == "human") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 14,
        'max': 76
    });
}
if (select.val() == "domovoi") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 26,
        'max': 254
    });
}
if (select.val() == "arcon") {
    $('#slider').prop({
        'min': 11,
        'max': 91
    });
}
if (select.val() == "tsaaran") {
              $('#slider').prop({
                  'min': 2,
                  'max': 28
              });
        }
        $('#slider').val('max' / 2);
        $(output).html('Slide');


    }
```

and

```
    $(function(){
     //Range
      var slider = $("#slider")
      val =         slider.val()
      output = $("#output")
      set_min_max($('#Race') )  ;
 slider.on("change", function(){
     output.html($(this).val())});
            $('#Race').change(function () {set_min_max($(this))
            });
     });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HLez9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4LgAP/) fiddle.

I used the `$( "#slider" ).slider();` function of Jquery UI and made some changes in the min/max changing functions. You get a better compatibility than using the HTML5 solution.